# Why is volatile int convertible to int but volatile T is not convertible to T?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, volatile

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct type {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << std::is_convertible_v<volatile int, int> << " ";
    std::cout << std::is_convertible_v<volatile int, volatile int> << " ";
    std::cout << std::is_convertible_v<volatile type, type> << " ";
    std::cout << std::is_convertible_v<volatile type, volatile type> << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out

> `1 1 0 0`

Why is `volatile int` convertible to `int`, but `volatile type` is not convertible to `type`? Why is a `volatile type` not even convertible to `volatile type`?

Is there a way to make a `volatile` class copyable?

Note: references to the C++ standard are welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicitly-declared default constructor for `type` has this signature

```
type::type(type const&);
```

The reference cannot bind to a volatile object, since that would discard qualifiers.

> **[class.copy.ctor]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#7) The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` will
> have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(const X&)
> ```
>
> if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type M (or array
> thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type
> `const M&` or `const volatile M&`. Otherwise, the implicitly-declared
> copy constructor will have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(X&)
> ```

Either way, the compiler isn't going to implicitly-declare a constructor that takes a reference to a volatile object.

The fact that the target object in the conversion is volatile too makes no difference. Such a conversion requires a copy constructor capable of binding to a volatile source.

Fundamental types aren't copied by constructors, so this behavior doesn't restrict them.

> Is there a way to make a `volatile` class copyable?

If it's required, you'd need to user-declared copy constructor that accepts by a reference to a `const volatile` object.

Comment: Nitpick: you *can* have a copy constructor that accepts by reference to **mutable** `volatile`, but *shouldn't*

Answer (score 1):

Such conversion to same type (with qualifiers ignored) is copying / moving.

`type` has an implicitly generated copy and move constructors which accept a reference to non-volatile qualified object. Such reference cannot be bound to a volatile argument, so conversion from volatile is not allowed.

There are no implicitly generated constructors accepting a reference to volatile qualified object. (Similarly, there are no implicit volatile qualified assignment operators, nor assignment operators with volatile qualified argument).

This is one of the ways C++ is incompatible with valid C where copying volatile structs is allowed.

> Is there a way to make a volatile class copyable?

You could technically define constructors that allow it:

```
struct type {
    type()                       = default;
    type(type          const & ) = default;
    type(type                &&) = default;
    type(type volatile const & ) {}
    type(type volatile       &&) {}
};
```

Depending on how you expect volatile to behave (access of volatile object is implementation defined), there may not necessarily be a way to implement this constructor in a way that you would expect copying from volatile object to behave if there are several subobjects.

Volatile class objects are generally not very useful, and are best to be avoided in my opinion.

Comment: Related - `volatile` deprecated in C++20 in some contexts:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59223814/why-is-volatile-deprecated-in-c20